# Templating in Airflow

Tags: templates, macros, jinja2, airflow

Folks, pretty new to Airflow. I am trying to send `start_date` and `end_date` to my sql script which is going to run as a task in my DAG. My initial approach was to template out these and send them to the `PostgresOperator` via `param` variable. Something like

```
PostgresOperator(
        task_id='test_edw_job',
        sql='sql/my.sql',
        params={'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date}
    )
```

where `start_date` and `end_date` are macros defined as

```
end_date = "{{ macros.my_plugin.end_date(execution_date) }}"

start_of_month = '{{ macros.my_plugin.start_date(execution_date) }}'
```

Inside my SQL file am accessing these variables as `{{ param.start_date }}` and `{{ params.end_date }}` respectively.

But once I start my DAG and look at the rendered task its templating out the them as `{{ macros.my_plugin.start_date(execution_date) }}` and `{{ macros.my_plugin.end_date(execution_date) }}` where as am trying to get the actual values of these macros be templated here. Am I doing something inherently wrong here ? Any inputs would be highly apprecaited.

Comment: Where are the end_date and state_date being set? in an html input? If these templates are in a python file they will probably not behave as you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, doing more digging into how templating works in Airflow. There is only one pass where the `params` would be replaced by its values. In my case `params` i.e. `start_date` and `end_date` are themselves templates which means they would be replace by their corresponding macro definitions (i.e `{{ macros.my_plugin.start_date(execution_date) }}` ) but not with the output of those `macros` i.e. something like `2019-10-10`. On doing some trial runs I figured out that I don't really had to pass in `start_date` and `end_date` as params to the `PostgresOperator`. I could just template out `start_date` and `end_date` in my Sql file and as part of initial pass of templating these variables will the replaced by their corresponding values as computed via `macros` representing them.

Hopefully this will help someone in future who is as new to templating in `airflow` as I am.